# select distinct rows from a table using different conditions using a single mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'scoretable', containing a 'name', a 'scoretask1' and a 'scoretask2' column, from which I want to select exact 15 distinct names every time, based on the following 3 criteria:
* 5 names should be selected randomly
* 5 names should be the names of those with the highest score for task1
* 5 names should be the names of those with the highest score for task2

I figured out how to build the queries for each of these three select statements, for example, for the first I used

```
select name from scoretable order by rand() limit 5;
```

The other two statements use the same `limit 5` clause
Finally, I've tried to combine the output of the three queries with a union statement, and as it produces a distinct output set by default this would solve my issue. However, in this case I will end up with result sets that do not always contain 15 rows, as the union filters out doubles at the moment of combining the three statements. Is there a way to produce a single mysql statement that will produce exact 15 distinct names based on the conditions above? (You can assume that there are enough names in the list to at least output 15 distinct names).

To clarify the expected behaviour:
* The selection of the top 5 names for task1 has priority and thus are always selected.
* Then the top 5 for task2 should be selected. If one of these names is present in the previous selection, the list will be extended with number 6, then number 7 and so on.
* Finally 5 random names should be selected from the remaining names; so not yet present in the previous selections.

Below the create table statement and value entry:

```
CREATE TABLE `scoretable` (
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `scoretask1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scoretask2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `scoretable` VALUES ('Barney',9,6),('Ben',10,9),('Bert',7,5),('Bryan',10,6),('Charles',4,5),('Dan',5,8),('Danny',6,6),('David',7,7),('Debby',8,7),('Eleonore',6,8),('Gerald',4,10),('James',7,2),('Jeff',5,6),('Jenny',4,6),('John',3,2),('Lana',8,4),('Liam',9,9),('Lisa',0,8),('Loreen',7,9),('Louise',5,6),('Marc',10,8),('Maria',2,5),('Mauro',8,6),('Megan',7,6),('Michael',3,8),('Mick',3,6),('Mike',2,1),('Rachel',2,7),('Rita',9,9),('Sheryl',2,9),('Tom',4,7),('Yasmin',7,10);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sounds like you need `UNION ALL`

Comment: @LoztInSpace No because in that case I could have the same name multiple times in the result set. The result set has to be distinct.

Comment: I've added the create table statement and value set.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Union all will combine them properly but what if a random name is the same as a task1 score, or taslk1 is also top 5 of tadk2?

Comment: @LoztInSpace What is expected for example, when you look at the scoretable, you  will notice that 'Rita' is in the top five for scoretask1 and thus will be selected. As she is also in the top five for scoretask2, I don't want to see her name twice, but I want to see the name of number 6 for scoretask2.I hope this helps to understand what I want to achieve.

Comment: It does but you need to specify all the rules. You are selecting 3 times. What has priority? What if all task1 are the same as task2? Is it supposed to return places 6 to 10?

Comment: @LoztInSpace That's right. Let's say the top five of task1 has priority, than the top five of task2 and finally the random selection.